# Accessibility issue with aria-controls

Tags: accessibility, voiceover, jaws-screen-reader

I am working on a requirement which has a button, and upon clicking on a button, a new `panel` opens on the right side.

Using `aria-controls` i was able to get JAWS announce when a new `panel` opens up(when the button is clicked). But, it does not work with Voice Over(VO). Can anyone suggest how to make it work on both JAWS and VO?

For reference i am attaching a screenshot of the UI[image]

Answer (score 2):

Last time I checked, aria-controls was not supported by any screen readers other than JAWS. This is most likely because many people feel the `aria-controls` purpose and functionality are not clearly defined. JAWS has implemented some functionality, but some people feel that it makes assumptions on functionality that are not necessarily in the best interest. Here are a couple of resources explaining this:

http://www.heydonworks.com/article/aria-controls-is-poop

https://tink.uk/using-the-aria-controls-attribute/

It's also worth keeping in mind that support for aria is still growing, so eventually, hopefully, these resources will no longer be relevant.